# DiscordJS Error: TypeError: aliases.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Whenever I try to run any sort of command it keeps giving me the following error:

```
TypeError: aliases.forEach is not a function
```

Here's the code:

```js
const { prefix } = require("./sub/config.json");

module.exports = (client, aliases, callback) => {
    if (typeof aliases === "string") {
        aliases = [aliases];
    }

    client.on("message", (message) => {
        const { content } = message;

        aliases.forEach((alias) => {
            const command = `${prefix}${alias}`;

            if (content.startsWith(`${command} `) || content === command) {
                console.log(`Running the command ${command}`);
                callback(message);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Literary this means that you alias is not a type of array. You're checking if that is string but you don't ensure that is not null, undefined or object. Maybe just if is not instaceof Array then create array.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like aliases isn't an array. To ensure that it is one replace

```
if (typeof aliases === "string")
```

with

```
if (typeof aliases !== "object)
```